# Question on elementary Linear Algebra product

Tags: matrices, vectors

I came across this in a problem:

$$\frac{\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}+\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}}{1+\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}}$$

Then, in order to simplify this, I thought the following:

\begin{gather}
\frac{\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}+\mathbf{u}\color{red}{\left(\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}\right)}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}}{1+\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}}\\
\frac{\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}+\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\color{red}{\left(\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}\right)}}{1+\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}}\\
\frac{\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\left(1+\color{red}{\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}}\right)}{1+\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}}\\
\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}
\end{gather}

I figured that this could be done because of associativity and as the terms in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ result in a scalar, it could be 'moved around'. Is this correct? If yes, does this always hold or are there any conditions on the vectors and matrices involved?

Comment: Correct, and it always holds (as long as $A$ is invertible of course).

Comment: @amsmath great, thx!